# Break out of overflow:hidden

Tags: css, css-position

We are currently struggling trying to break out of an div having overflow hidden.

We have a dropdown-menu that gets filled with suggestions when the user type (type 'c' in the search field to see). This dropdown-menu is currently hidden behind the menubar, because it has "overflow hidden".

We can break out, if we remove the `top:100%` and set position to `fixed`. But we would like it to stay absolute (i.e. for mobile devices).

Created an example here: https://edukarma.com/bootstrap/

The dropdown suggestion list can be found in `.headerItem.headerSearch .searchField .twitter-typeahead .tt-dropdown-menu`.

Comment: Do you need to use overflow: hidden? You could set it to visible and clear: both afterwards.

Comment: What you want is to show the drop down? Why don't you take out the overflow: hidden?

Comment: Please provided a reduced test case in the future. When people have to guess what you’re actually trying to solve we often guess wrong. ;)

Comment: If you’re not sure what that is you can find more information here: http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible workaround is to replace `overflow:hidden` with the following:

```
.navbar .headerItem.headerSearch {
  display: table; /* like overflow, creates new block formatting context */
  margin-left: 180px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.navbar .headerItem.headerSearch:after {
  /* hack to make the table use all available width */
  content: '. .';
  /* with such big spacing, the 2nd dot will always wrap to the new line,
     making the table-like block use the width of the container
     instead of shrinking to content */
  word-spacing: 99in;
  /* make this helper invisible */
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wow - amazing. It works. We have been fouling around with this for 6 hours now, actually also with table, but not this way. Cool!

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this issue and it can be quite frustrating. However after reading [this article](http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent), I found the suggested answer to be quite satisfying.

Essentially, You must specify an outer parent (add a 'grandparent' tag) to be explicitly `position:relative;` (with overflow unspecified) and the direct parent to be `overflow:hidden;` instead of having both of these CSS options directly applied on the same direct parent.

The examples provided (for completeness and in case the 2012 article is lost):

### Not working

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
  position:absolute; 
  top:-10px; 
  left:-5px;
}
```

### Working! (The Child is free to roam anywhere)

**HTML**

```
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grand-parent {
  position:relative;
}
.parent {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
  position:absolute; 
  top:-10px; 
  left:-5px;
}
```

Comment: I really liked the grand-parent/parent/child break down, it's super clear! Great explanation

Comment: @mcnutt Yes, of course! You gotta respect your elders ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is working. I had to remove the position: relative from the direct parent element to make it work. I expected my popup to jump up to the grandparent element with position: relative, but it stays where it is supposed to be. Is it magic, or am I being fooled by some annoying cache?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the child to be position: absolute.

HTML

```
<section>
    Parent
    <div>Child</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  overflow: hidden; /* BOOM */
}

section div {
  position: absolute; /* BOOM */
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background: gold;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/nukic/2/edit

Comment: Usually, this should work: `overflow: hidden` doesn't clip absolutely positioned descendants unless the same container doesn't have `position:relative` (see http://www.cssmojo.com/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/). But in this case, it doesn't help because there is relatively positioned intermediate container between the container with `overflow` and the element with `position:absolute`. The possible workaround I've desribed below.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @IlyaStreltsyn! That was not at all clear from the original question.